# python tkinter radiobutton state

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

How do you get the state of a `Button` (clicked or unclicked)? This is a button state and not a question about variables set by the button. How do I tell if an object in a `Frame` is selected using `i.winfo_class()` to identify a `Radiobutton`.

i.e.

```
for i in a.winfo_children():
    if i.winfo_class() == "Radiobutton":
        i.get()
```

Radiobuttons have no get attribute so this will never work, but the logic is the same. I've looked through documentation without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. `ttk.Radiobutton` has more functionality than the `tkinter.Radiobutton`.
**Please make note there there are major issues with all methods and values dereferences by Radiobuttons even now. Sometimes you get a pointer, sometimes you get a string and need to dereference yourself. This makes Radiobuttons a more difficult Widget to deal with than most of the others I've been working with. There are many documents on this and they are fixing this, but it is something to note.**
 For my purposes, `tkinter.Radiobutton` has no `instate` which means there is no simple way to check if it is clicked. I was getting pointer after pointer and dereferencing was far too tedious and complex to code for a dynamic gui.
The code I've ended up with is as follows:

```
for i in a.winfo_children():
    if i.winfo_class() == "TRadiobutton" and i.instate(['selected']) is True:
        return i.cget('value')
```

Also make note that `TRadioButton` string is used instead of `RadioButton`, the object type returned is not the same between `ttk` and `tkinter` implementations of Radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is to get the value of the associated variable and compare it to the value of the radiobutton. If they are the same, that radiobutton is selected.